# Trying to import a tikz figure generated by matplotlib2tikz, getting dimension too large for y-axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, matplotlib

I'm trying to use a graph exported by `matplotlib2tikz`, with the following code in it:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
ylabel={CF [\%]},
xmin=0.5, xmax=7.5,
ymin=0.096, ymax=0.144,
axis on top,
width=\figurewidth,
height=\figureheight,
legend entries={Without Daytime,With Daytime}
]
\addplot [red, dotted, mark=square*, mark options={draw=black}]
coordinates {
(1,0.133436580942456) (2,0.115673379339152) (3,0.120904949173964) (4,0.131747653060196) (5,0.132274436935023) (6,0.13189650135679) (7,0.131731186551343) 
};
\addplot [blue, dotted, mark=diamond*, mark options={draw=black}]
coordinates {
(1,0.109315022898981) (2,0.11263226182201) (3,0.113782540485058) (4,0.107637011084747) (5,0.108459720680927) (6,0.120093612355885) (7,0.120109008832872) 
};
\path [draw=black, fill opacity=0] (axis cs:13,1)--(axis cs:13,1);

\path [draw=black, fill opacity=0] (axis cs:1,13)--(axis cs:1,13);

\path [draw=black, fill opacity=0] (axis cs:13,0)--(axis cs:13,0);

\path [draw=black, fill opacity=0] (axis cs:0,13)--(axis cs:0,13);

\end{axis}
```

In my tex-file I have:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-fct} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\newlength\figureheight
\newlength\figurewidth
```

and:

```
\setlength\figurewidth{0.8\textwidth}
\setlength\figureheight{0.625\figurewidth}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\input{.fig1.tikz}
\caption{CAPTION}
\end{figure}
```

But this gives me: `! Dimension too large. <to be read again> ...`

Changing the `ymin` and `ymax` to 0 an 1.5 solves it but it doesn't look that good anymore.
I know I'm a real newbie when it comes to latex, but I hope someone could help me out.

Comment: The error occurs because of the four `\path` commands, which try to draw lines that lie far outside the plot area. If you delete them, everything works fine. What are they for (they don't produce anything visible in this plot)?

Comment: Thanks, that's wondefull, that just shows sometimes a fresh eye is all it needs.
I honestly don't know what the idea of those \path commands is, seems like some editing of the tikz files is almost always necessary when using matplotlib2tikz, but still it gives nice results.
Thanks

Comment: Glad the problem's solved! We'll probably close this as "too localized", if you don't mind?

Answer (score 0):

Use the new `pgf` backend in `matplotlib-1.2.0svn` instead of `matplotlib2tikz`. You need a recent LaTeX installation with LuaTeX or XeTeX.